# How to create arrow in a tkinter.ttk.Button and control it's size?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, ttk

I would like to create ttk.button with an arrow in it and have the arrow size changable.

I discovered 'TButton' inherently contains StyleNames `TButton.leftarrow` which is not exposed by the ttk.Style().layout().

**Questions:** 
(1) How do I activate these StyleNames? 
(2) How do I control the size of `.leftarrow`? I notice it has a `arrowsize` option . How do I use it?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(ttk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent):
            ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            self.parent = parent
            self.setStyle()
            self.setWidget()

        def setStyle(self):
            style = ttk.Style()
            print('Left.TButton layout are:', style.layout('Left.TButton'))
            print("Left.TButton.leftarrow style.element_options: ",
                  style.element_options('Left.TButton.leftarrow'))

            style.configure('Left.TButton', background='yellow')
            style.configure('Left.TButton.leftarrow', background='white',
                            arrowsize=20)

        def setWidget(self):
            self.lbutton = ttk.Button(self.parent, style='Left.TButton')
            self.lbutton2 = ttk.Button(self.parent, style='Left.TButton.leftarrow')
            self.lbutton.pack()
            self.lbutton2.pack()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title('Test')
        root.geometry('200x50')
        app = App(root)
        app.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
```

Comment: I think you're asking too many questions that simplest answer is just to read the source code located under `.../Python3x/Lib/tkinter/ttk.py` or `.../Python/Python3x/tcl/tk8.6/ttk`.

Comment: Also I'd rather put this code on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for critique.

Comment: @Nae What is the difference between coderview from SO? I have not understood hence I asked the question.

Comment: The difference is, in codereview you're supposed to be suggested better practices on a working code, or that if your code is faulty in some test values AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After quite a lot of attempts and closer studies of the ttk documentations, I discovered the following:

1. To create a arrow in the button, I have to declare a `arrow` element
   as the child of the `focus` element in the layout of the custom style
   that is to be used for the `ttk.Button()` widget. To do this, I needed
   to use the `ttk.Style().layout()` method.
2. The size of the arrow is dependent on the font size of the label
   element. Therefore, a `label` element had to be declared in layout
   of the style `TButton`. The `arrowsize` option of the `arrowleft` element did not seem to work. I have commented out this line of code which did not work. However, the `arrowcolor` option of the `leftarrow` element does work. To adjust the `label` element's font size, the `ttk.Style().configuration` method was used.

Approach 2 in Test Script demonstrates the solution to my question.

[image: Arrow Button]

**Test Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setStyle()
        self.setWidget()

    def setStyle(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        print('\nDefault TButton layout:')
        print(style.layout('TButton'))

        print ('\nTButton Elements and their options:')
        print("border options: ", style.element_options('Button.border'))
        print("focus options: ",  style.element_options('Button.focus'))
        print("padding options: ",style.element_options('Button.padding'))
        print("label options: ",  style.element_options('Button.label'))
        print("arrow options: ",  style.element_options('Button.arrow'))

        print ('\nElement TButton.label and its options:')
        print("compound: ",  style.lookup('Button.label', 'compound'))
        print("space: ",     style.lookup('Button.label', 'space'))
        print("text: ",      style.lookup('Button.label', 'text'))
        print("font: ",      style.lookup('Button.label', 'font'))
        print("foreground: ",style.lookup('Button.label', 'foreground'))
        print("underline: ", style.lookup('Button.label', 'underline'))
        print("width: ",     style.lookup('Button.label', 'width'))
        print("anchor: ",    style.lookup('Button.label', 'anchor'))
        print("justify: ",   style.lookup('Button.label', 'justify'))
        print("wraplength: ",style.lookup('Button.label', 'wraplength'))
        print("embossed: ",  style.lookup('Button.label', 'embossed'))
        print("image: ",     style.lookup('Button.label', 'image'))
        print("stipple: ",   style.lookup('Button.label', 'stipple'))
        print("background: ",style.lookup('Button.label', 'background'))

        print ('\nElement TButton.arrow and its options:')
        print("background: ", style.lookup('Button.arrow', 'background'))
        print("relief: ",     style.lookup('Button.arrow', 'relief'))
        print("borderwidth: ",style.lookup('Button.arrow', 'borderwidth'))
        print("arrowcolor: ", style.lookup('Button.arrow', 'arrowcolor'))
        print("arrowsize: ",  style.lookup('Button.arrow', 'arrowsize'))

        #Define style Default.TButton with yellow background
        style.configure('Default.TButton', background='yellow')
        #Change the 2 options of the "label" element in its style's layout  
        style.configure('Default.TButton.label', foreground='red')
        style.configure('Default.TButton.label', borderwidth=20)
        print ('\nElement Default.TButton.label and its options (after configuration):')
        print("background: ",  style.lookup('Default.TButton.border', 'background'))
        print("borderwidth: ", style.lookup('Default.TButton.border', 'borderwidth'))

        #Approach 1
        #==========
        # Define style Left.TButton to show the following elements: leftarrow,
        #  padding, label 
        style.layout(
            'Left1.TButton',[
                ('Button.focus', {'children': [
                    ('Button.leftarrow', None),
                    ('Button.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                        ('Button.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'}
                         )]}
                     )]}
                 )]
            )
        #Change 3 options of the "arrow" element in style "Left.TButton"
        style.configure('Left1.TButton.leftarrow',
                        background='white',
                        borderwidth=10,
                        arrowsize=20)
        print('\nElement TButton.arrow and its options (after changing):')
        print("background: ",  style.lookup('Left1.TButton.arrow','background'))
        print("borderwidth: ", style.lookup('Left1.TButton.arrow','borderwidth'))
        print("arrowsize: ",   style.lookup('Left1.TButton.arrow','arrowsize'))

        #Approach 2
        #==========
        style.layout(
            'Left2.TButton',[
                ('Button.focus', {'children': [
                    ('Button.leftarrow', None),
                    ('Button.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
                        ('Button.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'}
                         )]}
                     )]}
                 )]
            )

        style.configure('Left2.TButton',font=('','20','bold'), width=1, arrowcolor='white')
        #style.configure('Left2.TButton', width=1, arrowcolor='white', arrowsize='20')
        #option arrowsize does not work


    def setWidget(self):
        self.lbutton = ttk.Button(self.parent, style='Default.TButton',
                                  text='Default.TButton')
        self.lbutton1 = ttk.Button(self.parent, style='Left1.TButton',
                                   text='Left1.Button')
        self.lbutton2 = ttk.Button(self.parent, style='Left2.TButton',
                                   text='')
        self.lbutton.pack()
        self.lbutton1.pack()
        self.lbutton2.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Test')
    root.geometry('200x100')
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the the arrowsize did work with the following code. It is really the same code as @Sun-Bear's.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def cmd():
    pass

class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setStyle()
        self.setWidget()

    def setStyle(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.layout('Left.TButton', [ ('Button.focus', {'children': [ ('Button.leftarrow', None) ] } ) ] )
        style.configure('Left.TButton', font=('','60'), arrowcolor='green', arrowsize='40')

    def setWidget(self):
        self.lbutton3 = ttk.Button(self.parent, style='Left.TButton', command=cmd)
        self.lbutton3.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Test')
    root.geometry('100x200')
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```