# How to justify text in a Button in Python ttk

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to justify (align) text in a button, let's say to the left.
I've found some useful code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770877/how-to-create-arrow-in-a-tkinter-ttk-button-and-control-its-size), based on that I've created code below to check how the label behaves.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


app = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.layout(
        'Left1.TButton',[
            ('Button.button', None),
            ('Button.focus', {'children': [                
                ('Button.padding', {'children': [
                    ('Button.label', {'side' : 'left'}
                     )]}
                 )]}
             )]
        )

print("TButton.label->justify: ", style.lookup('TButton.label', 'justify'))
print("TButton.label->side: ", style.lookup('TButton.label', 'side'))

style.configure('TButton.label', justify='left')
style.configure('TButton.label', side='left')

print("TButton.label->justify: ", style.lookup('TButton.label', 'justify'))
print("TButton.label->side: ", style.lookup('TButton.label', 'side'))


ttk.Button(text="TButton", width=100, style="TButton").pack()
ttk.Button(text="Lef1.TButton", width=100, style="Left1.TButton").pack()

print("TButton.label options:\n", style.element_options('TButton.label'))
```

Problem is that there's no effect on the label. It stays in the center of the button.
What is even more interesting is last line.
Output is:

```
TButton.label options:
 ('compound', 'space', 'text', 'font', 'foreground', 'underline', 'width', 'anchor', 'justify', 'wraplength', 'embossed', 'image', 'stipple', 'background')
```

But if I try to set 'anchor' I'm getting exception. I know this feature is absent in ttk but why is it showing up here?

Comment: This might be a platform-specific thing. What platform are you running on? I know that on OSX, for example, there are some things the underlying native button simply won't allow.

Comment: Windows 10 but I've checked on Linux (Kali) and it also didn't work.

Comment: Anchor not throwing an exception for me, though not changing anything either. What is your system?

Comment: Forgot to add that I'm using Python 3.6.4. Are you using Button from ttk? I think the one from standard Tkinter does have anchor property. You can use it while creating the button.

Answer (score 0):

I've just been using the following style and it's working - this applies the anchor='center' configuration to all of my buttons, but you can create your own style for each wherein you just change 'TButton' to '{insert your style name}.TButton' (more on that `https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/ttk-style/` - underrated resource to learn ttk styling).

Anyways, here's the code:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_create( "button-center", parent="alt", settings={
        "TButton": {"configure": {"anchor": "center"}}} )

# Now just create the button itself

style.theme_use("button-center")
btn = ttk.Button({the_frame_it_belongs_to})
btn.configure(text='BUTTON', width='15')
btn.grid(column='0', row='0')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style: tkinter.ttk.Style = tkinter.ttk.Style()
# Justify to the left [('Button.label', {'sticky': 'w'})]
style.layout("TButton", [('Button.button', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Button.focus', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Button.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Button.label',
    {'sticky': 'w'})]})]})]})])
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.